# Display Product Field twice

Tags: entities, commerce, display-suite

I simply want to display Product Details twice on my page.

I use **Display Suite** for displaying all my fields on the node (Product Display) and for displaying the field twice, I would like to use a **Dynamic Field**. It lets me select the field but when I view my node I get a 500 Error.

Can someone help me please?
Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Display Suite to duplicate your fields, go into Structure -> Display Suite -> Fields and add a dynamic field. Fill out the details specific to your node, etc.

On the Manage Display page of your content type you need to configure this field and select your product details, etc.