# How-to display a product variation field twice (or more)?

Tags: 7, commerce, display-suite

I want simply display a field of a *product variation* type (commerce) two times with different render settings.

[I have tried with a dynamic field](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/150700/display-product-field-twice) (display_suite) but it not working... I would prefer to know a **programmatically** solution to accomplish this task and I want use the (Drupal core) ***Display Manager*** for designate my layout (not a template file) :)

**Note:** This product field do automatically refresh (ajax) like other when a different product variation is selected.

See this related "issue": https://www.drupal.org/node/1494192#comment-7031370

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [`template_preprocess_node()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7) to duplicate a field.

I've not run this code and just written it from memory but something like this should suffice:

```
function template_preprocess_node(&$variables) {

  // Check this is the node type for commerce products
  if($variables['node']['#type'] == 'product') {

    // Copy the existing field to a new item
    $variables['content']['YOUR_FIELD_2'] = $variables['content']['YOUR_FIELD'];

    // Now make any changes to how you want to render the duplicate field
  }

}
```